# What to do when in Malaysia and visa expires during lockdown?

Tags: tourist-visas, malaysia, covid-19, visa-extensions

I am currently in Malaysia on a 30 day visitor visa. My flight is April 6th, but all flights have been cancelled until further notice. There is no avenue for me to leave the country. My visa expires on April 7th. I’ve tried calling the Indonesian embassy in Malaysia but not once have they picked up; I assume this is because the country is in lockdown.

I need urgent help and advice. I’m not sure what to do, and don’t want to be penalized with overstaying.

Answer (score 30):

**UPDATE:** Flights are operating to Indonesia that allows you to fly out, at a very reasonable price. The below advice still applies if your host country ceased flights, like India, or your country of citizenship ceased flights (again India).

You have to contact Malaysian Immigration to know about the stay extension. This is a circumstance beyond your control, they should be able to help you on extension of your stay. Indonesian embassy have limitations on involving in visa policies of host country. If you are looking to go home, Indonesian embassy may help in form of an evacuation flight (unlikely in this scenario) or similar.

If you just want to extend the stay, Assuming you are in KL, this is the contact details.

> Jabatan Imigresen Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur,Aras LG, 1,2 & 5,
> Kompleks Kementerian Dalam Negeri (KDN),  No 69, Jalan Sri Hartamas 1,
> Off Jalan Duta,  50550, Kuala Lumpur
>
> **Tel: 03-62057400**
>
> Fax: 03-62011191

Further contact details can be found in the following websites.

- https://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/contact-us/address-and-locations.html
- https://www.imi.gov.my/images/alamat-cawangan/KL.pdf

Comment: Update: India operates its own charted flights for stranded citizens at a cost. Contact Indian embassy of your country to know if you are eligible or when such a flight is available.

Answer (score 3):

Today is DAY 75 (31/05/2020) of the Malaysian Lockdown.

This is the latest statement on 28 May 2020 from a Senior Minister (Defence).

[image]

In Malaysia the **Visa** system is slightly different from the western countries. A **VISA** is required to enter and a **VISIT Pass** of 30 days is given to Indonesians.
Read the stamp on your passport "entry stamp" properly.

You have already "**overstayed**" by normal immigration policies. But because of the Lockdown in both countries, there is no International Passenger Flights as yet.

There is no need to apply for a ***Special Pass*** (Extension of stay) while the lockdown is in force.

Check with your Embassy. They should be opened now. If there is a need for you to go back urgently due work or family commitments, there are Mercy Flights, Chartered Flights organized by the Embassy.

Below is another statement dated 19 March 2020, one day after the lockdown started. It is direct from the Director General of Immigration.

[image]

Comment: Jeff Lee, please quote the relevant documents and provide a link to their web address, if you only have them on paper please quote and add the photo. Text in pictures does not work for rwading assist apps and is often difficult to read even for people without restrictions.

Comment: For the first pic there is a link but no use to others trying to access it because one have to register with the website news web page. The second pic has no links at all as it is a privileged doc send to Embassies.

Comment: The links are not the important part, the quoting of the text is. (Imagine having eye problems and not being able to read, find this answer and then not be able to have your app read out the relevant texts.)